# Extract URL from specific pattern (Google Alert)

Tags: sed, grep, url

I have tried every possible (to my poor knowledge) combination of grep and sed commands, but fail to extract URLs with the following pattern (Google Alert e-mails in plaintext):

```
"url": "https://www.google.com/url?rct=3Dj\u0026sa=3Dt\u0026url=3Dhtt=
p://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/judge-orders-forfeiture-cartel-money-launde=
ring-case-44765120\u0026ct=3Dga\u0026cd=3DCAEYACoTNzAxNDE5ODc4MzMzMTc5OTA4O=
TIaYjdkMGIxMjNmMjc0YWM4ODpjb206ZW46VVM\u0026usg=3DAFQjCNHKeTb3brU2sr0qOpXXJ=
fuW9Nfntg"
```

Obviously, what I want to extract is:

```
http://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/judge-orders-forfeiture-cartel-money-laundering-case-44765120
```

So I need to extract what is between "url=3D" and "\".

I have tried all kinds of grep and sed variations, but nothing works.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me figure this out.

PS: I know that once the URLs extracted I'll have to deal with the = characters, but one problem at a time :)

Comment: Maybe you should deal with "=\n" first, to join it into a single line, and then you can `sed` it (or do that joining in the `sed` program).

Comment: thanks, the problem is that when performing on a file with many such patterns, it doesn't work (it works only if I put this pattern only in a single file or as an echo input)

Comment: Hmm, apparently your `sed` doesn't have `-z`, then. If it had, you wouldn't end up with any lines ending in '='. You may need to highlight that in your question. Check `man sed` and `sed --version`

Comment: sed version is sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 and I do have -z (just checked it with man)

Comment: Due to the complexity of the file formatting, I think what I should be able to do is: print all lines that contains url=3D BUT print only what comes AFTER url=3D, AND print UNTIL the line that contains u0026ct BUT print only what comes before u0026ct. This way I may be able to escape the problem caused by the formatting, which causes sed and grep to stop at each end of line? But I have no idea of how to do it. As of now, I managed to print everything it matches the line containing u0026ct: `awk '{print} /u0026ct/ {exit}' INBOX > output.txt `...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line like the following for the processing:

```
cat INBOX | sed -z -e 's/=\n//g' | \
   sed -e 's/.*u0026url=3D//;t a;d;:a' -e 's/\\u0026ct=3D.*//'
```

The first `sed` step is for joining the lines the ends with "=" with their succeeding line, and thus in particular making one-liners of the interesting lines.

The second `sed` step firstly both reduces interesting lines by removing their head part, and discards any lines without that head, and secondly removes the tail parts of the target lines.

Comment: did you remember the `-z` to the first `sed`?

Comment: yes, I did exactly how you put it.

Comment: Peculiar; so doing the first `sed` only result in lines ending with `=`? I.e. doesn't join? Maybe your line ends are `\r` then (you are using a mac?) Try replacing `\n` with '`r'... or you're using windows? replace '\n` with `\r\n`...

Comment: I'm using Linux

Comment: Yes, but the file might have, say, Window's line endings. You might replace `\n` with `\r\?\n` so as to treat both window's and linux line endings as such.

Comment: THANKS!!!!! `cat INBOX | sed -z -e 's/=\r\?\n//g' | \
   sed -e 's/.*u0026url=3D//;t a;d;:a' -e 's/\\u0026ct=3D.*//' > output.txt` WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this command

```
awk -F"3D" '{print $4}' input.txt | sed "s/\\\u.*//"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your input, but it doesn't work: the command returns lots of broken links, such as: "https://www.google.com/a
http://rapsinews.com/judicial_news





"16" style
US&amp;r





"16"></a> </td> <td width
"https://www.google.com/aler
http://rapsinews.com/judicial_news/20
and so on...

Comment: why don't you post some of the lines from actual file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how you are getting the alerts but I will provide an example of how to do it if the alerts were in a simple text file. I would deal with the "=" first by using tr then I would use Pearl lookarounds with grep as follows ...

```
cat input.txt | tr --delete '=\n'| grep -oP '(?<=url3D).*?(?=\\u0026)' input.txt
```

The output using your sample is

```
http://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/judge-orders-forfeiture-cartel-money-laundering-case-44765120
```

Comment: I perform the extractions on a single INBOX file (thunderbird). Thanks for your suggestion, it works flawlessly if performed on a file containing ONLY this sample, however when performed on the INBOX file (with many such URLs), it doesn't work at all (output is the same as the input). I really don't know what's wrong. As I have already mentioned, the pattern is always the same (URLs are located between  u0026url=3D and \u0026ct=)

Comment: the weird thing is that until it encounters another instance of "url": , the command you suggest works as intended and ignores all non-relevant strings (lot of html code and useless text), but whenever it encounters the next "url":, it breaks (stops extracting and just puts the rest of the INBOX file content after the first extracted URL)

Comment: Well we are part of the way there then. :) If you would like to edit your question and provide a more complete example (with 2+ urls) I'd be happy to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Question solved using the suggestion of Ralph Rönnquist

`cat INBOX | sed -z -e 's/=\r\?\n//g' | \ sed -e 's/.*u0026url=3D//;t a;d;:a' -e 's/\\u0026ct=3D.*//' > output.txt`

It takes a long time to compute, but it does extract the URLs correctly.

Thanks a lot everybody for your assistance!